# Sendgrid sample example is not working and how to email to multiple recipients?

Tags: python, twilio, sendgrid

I've create an API Key as required by the code and added it in the environments.
Below is the code I'm using and have followed the steps provided [**here.**](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/python)

```
# using SendGrid's Python Library
# https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email='from_email@example.com',
    to_emails='to@example.com',
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sendgrid_email.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(e.message)
AttributeError: "ForbiddenError" object has no attribute "message"
```

And while **printing exception** it shows pylint warning-

```
Instance of "Exception" has no "message" member
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Also, `to_emails` is having only one email address, **how do we attach multiple recipients?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give API Key its full access, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. API Keys
3. Edit API Key
4. Full Access
5. Update

---

Whitelist your domain, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. Sender Authentication
3. Domain Authentication
4. Select DNS Host
5. Enter your domain name
6. Copy all records and put them in your Advanced DNS management console

NOTE: When adding records, make sure not to have domain name in the host. Crop it out.

If you do not want to authenticate domain, you can try with **Single Sender Verification** as well.

Note: It might take some time for records to start functioning.

---

If you're using pylinter, `e.message` will say

```
Instance of 'Exception' has no 'message' member
```

This is because `message` attribute is generated dynamically by `sendgrid` which pylinter is unable to access as it doesn't exists before runtime.

So, to prevent that, at the top of your file or above `print(e.message)` line, you need to add either one of the below, they mean the same thing-

```
# pylint: disable=no-member
```

E1101 is code to `no-member`, fine more [here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html#id6)

```
# pylint: disable=E1101
```

---

Now the code below should work for you. Just make sure you have `SENDGRID_API_KEY` set in environment. If not, you may also directly replace it with `os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY")` which is not a good practice though.

```
# pylint: disable=E1101

import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email="from_email@your-whitelisted-domain.com",
    to_emails=("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com"),
    subject="Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
    html_content="<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>")
try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

---

`to_emails` can receive tuple for multiple recipients. e.g.

```
to_emails=("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com"),
```

Comment: Wow, just the perfect answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, didn't realize you needed to use your whitelisted "from_email" in example.  Also double check that the IP address from the source computer is whitelisted in the "IP Access Management" section.